# How can I import a mid-size JSON export into Etherpad Lite?

Tags: json, import, data-migration, etherpad

I am trying to migrate a single pad from an externally hosted Etherpad
Lite instance to a self hosted one. I would like to preserve the pad
history.

As I can not access the backend, I exported an `*.etherpad` JSON file of
about 2.7 MB size via the original pad's web interface.

Trying to import this via the web interface in the new pad apparently
uploads the file, but then yields the error "*Import failed: Please copy and paste*".

There apparently are no errors on the browser's JS console.

The server console also displays no errors.

As I have console access, I could also import the file on the command line, but I could not find a script in the Etherpad Lite installation to do this.

How can I import the `*.etherpad` JSON file into the new pad, preserving the
history?

Comment: Have you tried reloading the page after the import? Helped for me.

Comment: Also, the request is sent via an iframe, so the request, at least for me, only appears in the browser console (Firefox), which btw is a success, even for 7MB ^^ Sounds like it's a timeout in the JS frontent or sth like that.